# Populate Data From SharePoint List to a SQL Table

Tags: list, infopath, sql-server

Is there a way that I can populate a custom share point list into a table in SQL server Database . I have a custom list which I modified and made it as an info path form and on submit I want the values entered by the user be populated in a SQL table. Please help me. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably help you (from Codeplex): [Microsoft SQL Server Community Samples: Integration Services](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/)

With the above app  you can transfer data between SharePoint and SQL Database (both ways). With some sql server jobs, you can keep data relatively synced, not dynamically though. The product is free.

Answer (score 0):

If you want:

- "i want that the values entered by the user must be populated in a SQL table
  want "the values entered by the user"

then you shouldn't have made

- "a custom list which i modified it and made it as an info path form and on submit"

which I understand as Infopath form was made by pressing a violet button "Modify Form" on ribbon.

In this case the "the values entered by the user" are already persisted by Infopath form of type/compatibility "Sharepoint List Form" through auto-created and locked as non-modifiable during Infopath form creation **Main Data Connection** (of type **Main Data Source**) onto a sharepoint list.

The sharepoint list data is stored by Sharepoint server into SQL Server Content database for you automatically by design.  And this is unrelated to Infopath

Any reason why do you want to persist data redundantly both into a sharepoint list and into a custom SQL Server database?

Update:
I also wrote initially...
Either it is possible through Sharepoint what is most probably not your intention when you asked about submit from Infopath form. From Infopath you should not do it through Sharepoint List Form...
While it is possible to do from Infoapth, you should have asked **WHAT** you want to do but not **HOW** (eventually you can not).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gennady, but if you insist than you can create a SharePoint list item event handler and on "ItemAdded" event and then you fetch all the list item column values by SharePoint object model.

Once you have performed this step you would then need to make a stored procedure in the SQL database to SET the data in. Another good step is to first check to see if you not returning the same values into the database to save on resources so that only new data get persisted on to sql server.

This is a nice little article that might help you out that you could change to suite your needs http://www.directsharepoint.com/2011/02/dump-sharepoint-list-data-into-sql.html

hope this helps